# NotFoundException for activity_fullscreen

Tags: android

I get an NotFoundException. I already found out with R.java that it is activity_fullscreen which is not found. It is in the same place as it is in the fullscreenactitivty which is created as an example by eclipse which works fine. But mine won't run.
Source:

```
package com.example.dreamadventure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;

private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hintergrund);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eulenloch);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
   <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/hintergrund" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:src="@drawable/eulenloch"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </ImageView>

  </View>
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you include you logcat log

Comment: What's the name of the folder that contains activity_fullscreen.xml??

Answer (score 0):

A view can not hold any other view, your layout file is wrong, use LinearLayout instead of View, Clean your project and it will work

Update

```
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

use this filter insteed of above in you activity in mainfest

```
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't. In eclipse it says: "[2013-02-22 10:56:51 - Dreamadventure] /Dreamadventure/bin/Dreamadventure.apk installed on device
[2013-02-22 10:56:51 - Dreamadventure] Done!" But nothing happens on the device and the app is not showing in the installed apps on the device.

Comment: can you paste your mainfest file

Comment: change default to LAUNCHER in your mainfest

Comment: after that it says "unfortunately dreamadventure has stopped". No error in eclipse-console.

Comment: logcat is empty, console says: [2013-02-23 08:15:53 - Dreamadventure] Starting activity com.example.dreamadventure.FullscreenActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-02-23 08:15:57 - Dreamadventure] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.dreamadventure/.FullscreenActivity }

Comment: Nobody got any idea left why this isn't working? I hate it when there are no errors but it doesn't work... no idea where to look :(